# setting section number, etc with counter

Tags: numbering, theorems

Originally, I have these types of numbering:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} 
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Now because of the box theorem function, I modified them to below:

```
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{theorem}{Theorem}{mycounter}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{definition}{theorem}{mycounter}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{lemma}{theorem}{mycounter}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{proposition}{theorem}{mycounter}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{corollary}{theorem}{mycounter}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{example}{theorem}{mycounter}

\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{mycounter}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

My numbering system is now messed up.

For example:
Hope I am right in explaining like this: Originally, before I add in the function that will "box theorem" I have the following numbering system: Chapter I, Section 1, Theorem 1 will be identified as Theorem 1.1. If you use eqnarray then it will be listed as I.1.1. For subsection, there is no effect, the theorem number will just move on like Theorem 1.2, Theorem 1.3 and so forth but once I have new section, the cycle will restart, in other words Theorem 2.1, Theorem 2.2, etc and when using eqnarray, I will have I.2.1, I.2.2 
 Now in the second chapter, the theorem will be II.1.1 for Chapter 2, Section 1, Theorem 1, and so forth.

But now after I add in the "box theorem" function, my numbering messed up in other words the theorem just move on like. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 then 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 rather than 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.

### ORIGINAL HEADER

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{t1enc,mathrsfs,latexsym,amsmath,amsxtra,amsthm,amssymb,makeidx,graphics}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{arabtex}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color, fontenc, titlesec,amsfonts}
```

### MODIFIED HEADER

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{t1enc,mathrsfs,latexsym,amsmath,amsxtra,amsthm,amssymb,makeidx,graphics}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{arabtex}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color, fontenc, titlesec,amsfonts,boiboites}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you turn those code snippets into a minimal example?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @sandra: A "minimal example" would be a LaTeX file that actually generates the problems or issues you're encountering. The code snippets you've posted, by themselves, aren't really sufficient to generate the problem behavior. A "minimal example", then, would include a `\documentclass` command, the loading of all relevant packages and the set-ups of all macros you're using for the case at hand (including a definition of the counter "mycouner"), plus a `\begin{document} [some commands that generate the problems] \end{document}`.

Comment: What's the package that provides `\newboxedtheorem`?

Comment: Have you tried putting `\numberwithin{mycounter}{section}` instead of `\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{mycounter}`? You have to load package `amsmath` or `mathtools` to make it work.

Comment: @egreg I modified my post and you can follow the link to get the style file about the box theorem. The newboxedtheorem is to contain the theorem in a box.

Comment: @tohecz, amazing. I think your solution solve my problem. Now the other problem is all my lemmas, proposition, example turn into "theorem". Do you think there is a mistake in the coding itself?

Comment: That's another question, but try this: `\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,titleboxcolor = black]{lemma}{Lemma}{mycounter}`

Comment: @tohecz it worked but in my original file, the centre bracket is Theorem. Do you think there will be problem if I change to Lemma in terms of labelling in the future?

Comment: I don't know how `\newboxedtheorem` works, the last suggestion was just a blind try... But that has nothing to do with the original question I think so you should ask about this command in a seperate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A shot in the dark**

I asked Google about the comment `\newboxedtheorem` and found the following page:

[Nice boxes for your theorems with LaTeX using tikz](http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-en/index.php/post/2010/01/30/Nice-boxes-for-your-theorems-with-tikz)

There the *unsupported* package `boiboites` can be found. The code is very transparent and you can see that the command `\newboxedtheorem` doesn't support the manipulation of counters like `\netheorem`. You can set only one counter. The default usage is:

```
\newboxedtheorem{defi}{Definition}{thCounter}
```

So
your code fails

```
\newboxedtheorem[]{example}{theorem}{mycounter}
```

because you have to many arguments.

To allow the possibility of `\newtheorem` you have to change the code of `boiboites.sty`.

---

As discussed in the chat the package has no license information and must be classified as *non-free*. So you can download the code and use but I don't know whether we can manipulate this code here.

Comment: Hi Marco, I am a newbie in tex, so I don't know how to change the code. Can we edit style file?

Comment: @sandra: Please see my edit (last lines). You can have a look at the package tcolorbox.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. Sorry for not knowing this in advance and glad you let me know about this.

Answer (score 3):

You should put

```
\numberwithin{mycounter}{section}
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{mycounter}
```

You have to load package `amsmath` or `mathtools` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbering of your theorems to go back to zero whenever you enter a new section in your document, you should use this option in the `\newboxedtheorem` macro:

`thcounter=section`

Just add it along with the color options. Then, you can do:

`\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{mycounter}}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.